# Computer won't start after changing power options

Tags: laptop, power-management

Have a older IBM thinkpad with Vista that worked fine, but it it started not to log off..so I read some threads and changed all the power options to "do nothing" because I thought it was going into hibernate mode..anyway...now it won't light up and start ...dead nothing.  Took battery out and in...dead.  Is there anyway to get it started again and go back and change the settings.

Comment: Is there any sound when you try to start it?  What do you mean by not log off?

Comment: It could be just a coincidence and your motherboard (for example) has just failed. Take it to a local computer shop they should be able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Changing the power settings in Vista has no effect on whether or not a computer POSTs properly, and if you aren't even getting any power response at all, then it is certainly a hardware failure and not a software one. Be sure that the power jack has not come loose from the motherboard (rarer on thinkpads, but it does happen), and also try to start it with no battery in it at all. Chances are the board is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Check your power supply, your laptop may have been shutting itself off because the battery was getting low and now it is completely discharged so it won't attempt to start at all.